# How to get a proper restaurant bill setText?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

this is the code I used for the restaurant bill. I want the outcome like a real recipe, but the problem is the text I get is next to each other instead of underneath. [This is the outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqfZl.png).

Can someone help me with this?

```
BonField.setText("\tKassabon\n" +
    "Klantnummer:" + klant + 
    "\n=================================================================\t " +
            "\n======================================================\t " +
            "\nBtw 6%:\t\t\t\t\t" + BTW +
            "\nSub Totaal:\t\t\t\t\t" + SubTotaal +
            "\nTotaal bedrag:\t\t\t\t\t" + Totaal +
            "\nContant betaald:\t\t\t\t\t" + Totaal +
            "\n======================================================\t " +
            "\nDatum: " + Tdate.format(timer.getTime()) +
                    "\t\tTijd: " + tTime.format(timer.getTime()) +
    "\n\n\tBedankt voor uw bezoek, graag tot ziens\n" );
```

Comment: Don't share screenshots of the code. Just copy-paste them in the question

Comment: Thanks, just did it.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* look of the output.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: **Never** format your textbox or **any other visual element** by it content directly in final builds of your applications. Although it is understandable for debug usage and stuff, you'll probably need to handle **auto adjustment** things within final builds.

Secondly: Too few info to help you, bro. Think and express properly when asking questions or you'll keep having your questions underrated.

Good luck with your work!